# Retrieve commits containing a given blobID

Tags: git, version-control

#### The problem

I am working on a git repository. I have a `blobID`, that I know is from this repository. I want to list all commits in which this `blobId` is involved.

Looking at some existing StackOverflow questions, I came up with the following command :

```sh
git log --oneline --find-object <blobID>`
```

**Yet, for some `blobIDs`, I don't get any output...**

#### How to reproduce

- Clone [git](https://github.com/git/git) from GitHub.
- We want to list all commits that contain the following blobID : `8b01793845ff65b7e3244259842af3d3de63e0a1`
- `git log --oneline --find-object 8b01793845ff65b7e3244259842af3d3de63e0a1` does not yield anything.
- Yet, the commit `27d7c8599b` clearly introduces this blobIdD for the file `t/t5323-pack-redundant.sh`

Would you have an explanation for such a behaviour ?
And hence, a proposition for a correct command to achieve my goal.

Comment: The reproducer here was extremely helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: it's those darned merges again.  Use `-m`.

```
$ git log --oneline --find-object 8b01793845ff65b7e3244259842af3d3de63e0a1
```

indeed prints nothing at all.  My first suspicion was that if it was new enough, we might need `--all` or `--remotes` to find the object via some remote-tracking name, but that makes no difference here.  However:

```
$ git log -m --oneline --find-object 8b01793845ff65b7e3244259842af3d3de63e0a1
6aae0e2ad2 (from 6aac70a870) Merge branch 'jh/simple-ipc-sans-pthread'
36a255acd1 (from 1e1c4c5eac) Merge branch 'zh/ref-filter-push-remote-fix'
e004fd6b69 (from e6f68f62e0) Merge branch 'ls/typofix'
52371bf449 (from 3a7f0908b6) Merge branch 'mt/clean-clean'
    [many more output lines snipped]
27d7c8599b (from 8b70966aa9) Merge branch 'js/default-branch-name-tests-final-stretch'
```

> Yet, the commit `27d7c8599b` clearly introduces this blobIdD for the file `t/t5323-pack-redundant.sh`

Indeed, it's the last commit in the output above.

> Would you have an explanation for such a behaviour ?

It's carefully hidden in plain sight in the `--find-object` description in [the `git log` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

> `--find-object=<object-id>`
>       Look for differences that change the number of occurrences of the specified object. Similar to `-S`, just the argument is different in that it doesn’t search for a specific string but for a specific object id.

Now, we already know—well, we do if we've spent a lot of time fighting with Git —that `git log` by default *doesn't bother to do diffs at all* with merge commits.  This means that `-S` and `-G` *completely ignore merge commits* as well.  This trips everyone up at least once when searching for which merge commit completely dropped some code instead of fixing the conflict correctly.

Adding any of the diff-forcing options—`-m`, `-c`, or `--cc`—to `git log` forces it to generate a diff of each merge commit.  The combined diffs are often useless here as well, but the `-m` ones always work and always find us what we're looking for (provided we also know how to handle any problems introduced by History Simplification, that is).

Since `--find-object` is like `-S`, it needs the same handling.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer! I am still a bit puzzled by the output of the command with the `-m` option.   
Here is what I understand : the last commit displayed is the one that introduced the object. In this case it is a merge commit. But I can see mention of the object in any of the two parents ?  
All other commits displayed are posterior commits that occurred on branches created before the introduction of the object, resulting in a `change in the number of occurrences of the specified object` and hence displayed in the output of the command.  
Am I correct ?

Comment: @plalanne: every commit printed is one of the split-up merge commits. Basically we see the new blob appear (as a result of the initial merge that created it), and then we track its introduction into other merge commits as they merge in the commits that have the blob. The non-merges that have the blob match the parent commits that have the blob: those parents are themselves non-merges, or merges in which the blob appears on only one "leg".

Comment: We've taken each merge M with its two parents P1 and P2 and turned it into M'-P1 and M''-P2 pairs, and the *number of occurrences* of the object of interest is different in one of the pairs (M'-P1 or M''-P2: remember that the snapshot in M' or M'' is literally the snapshot in M). Which is, I think, another way of saying what you said: posterior commits resulting in a change in the number of occurrences of the specified object.